# How to create new variables (i.e., columns) for each value of a vector

Tags: vector, variable-assignment

I've got a dataset from which I've extracted a list of values and created a vector from them, for example:

> vec <- c('first','second','third')

What I want to do now is create a new variable for each value of the vector, so that when I'm done I'll have a variable named "first_vec", another named "second_vec", etc. These variables will then be populated using conditions.  Here's what I've tried:

```
vec <- c('first','second','third')

for (myvar in vec) {
df <- df %<%
   mutate(paste(org, "_vec", sep="") = case_when(df$condition == "first-condition" ~ "Low",
                                                 df$condition == "second-condition" ~ "Med",
                                                 df$condition == "third-condition" ~ "High")

df$condition <- replace_na(df$condition, "No")
}
```

If this all works, when I'm done, df will look something like this:
| first_vec | second_vec | third_vec |
|:---------:|:----------:|:---------:|
|    Low    |    Low     |    Med    |
|   High    |    Low     |    Med    |

etc.  The values don't matter in this table illustration; what matters is that I've been able to create, and then address, those columns in the "For" loop.

Obviously, I'm short-circuiting the preexisting conditions of the df because I am too brain-fogged to create the dummy dataset for them at the moment.  I hope from my logic you can see what I'm trying to accomplish.  The part(s) where I'm failing are the ability to use the vector name to create a variable column, and then to address that column with other mutate commands using the variable.